# Disable reduced motion on chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm using Macos and I've enabled reduced motion in the OS settings because I like it better that way, now a problem with this is that this enables the prefers reduced motion flag on google chrome too, which is a problem. Not only do I not really like it disabled, but I'm also a developer, so I kind of need that.

Does anyone know of a way to disable reduced motion on chrome?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable reduced motion because of the space switching? If so, try Yabai (on Github) and you can disable reduced motions again.